# Let $Y$ be the subspace of $B(\Bbb N, \Bbb F)$ consisting of those sequences tending to zero. Show that $Y$ is separable

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $Y$ be the subspace of $B(\Bbb N,\Bbb F)$ consisting of those sequences tending to zero.
Show that $Y$ is separable.
 Here $\Bbb F=   \Bbb C$ or $\Bbb R$ (field of complex numbers or real numbers), $\Bbb N$ is the field of natural numbers, and $B(\Bbb N,\Bbb F):= \{f : \Bbb N → \Bbb F : f \text{ is bounded}\}$.

Comment: A dense subspace is all sequences of rational numbers (or rational real and imaginary part) that are eventually $0$. (What topology do you consider on the space of bounded sequences?)

Comment: Thanks for the coment. this question was in the chapter of my book about metric spaces so, I am not sure what type of topologies you could consider in the space of bounded sequences, but you could turn it into a metric space through the metric: D(f,g) := sup x∈S d(f(x), g(x)).

Answer (score 1):

I assume $B(N,F)$ is a metric space with the metric $$d_\infty(x_n,y_n)=\sup_n \vert x_n-y_n \vert$$The set $$S:=\{y_n \in \Bbb Q: \text{finitely many $y_n$ are non zero }\}$$ is a countable dense subset of $Y$

---

Countable part is easy(?). For the other part, take $x_n=(x_1,x_2,...)\in Y$. Then $\lim x_n=0$. That is, $$(\forall \varepsilon>0:\exists N \in \Bbb N): \vert x_n \vert< \varepsilon$$ whenever $n >N$. Choose rational $y_1,y_2,...,y_N$ so that $\vert x_i-y_i \vert < \varepsilon$ for $1 \leq i \leq N$. Define $y_n=(y_1,y_2,..,y_N,0,0,\cdots,0)$, we have $y \in S$ and $$d_\infty(x_n,y_n) < \varepsilon$$

Comment: The question didn't specify any metrics, so the result should hold for any metric. Now, is S countable because it is a collection of countable sets? Also, the conclusion that $d(x_n,y_n)<ε$, implies that $B_ε(y_n)$ has non empty intersection with $\Bbb F$ for all ε>0? (here $B_ε(x)$ is just the open ball centered on x. )

Comment: Yes for the first one! For the second one, dense means for any $x_n \in Y$, there exists $y_n \in S$ so that $d(x_n , y_n)< \varepsilon$. Thats what I prove!

Comment: Oh, I see it now, the sequences from $S$ that need to have nonempty intersection with the sequences from $Y$ for any ε>0. Im insisting on this definition because it is the one used in my book. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Let $D$ be the set of sequences with rational values that have only at most finitely many non-zero values, This is essentially $\bigcup_n \mathbb{Q}^n$ so a countable set.

Then for any sequence $(x_n)$ tending to $0$ and any $\varepsilon>0$ find $N$ such that all $|x_n| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for $n \ge N$. Then note that $(x_1,\ldots,x_N)$ can be approximated in the sup-metric (on $N$ coordinates) by a rational vector $(q_1,\ldots,q_N)$ such that $\sup_{i=1,\ldots N} |x_i - q_i| < \varepsilon$.

Then $(q_1,\ldots, q_N,0,0,0,\ldots)$ is in $D$ and in $B((x_n),\varepsilon)$.

This shows density of $D$ in the set of sequences under consideration.